# Reactive stream on finite source remaining open for future events

Tags: spring-data, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Webflux, Spring Data, and Project Reactor for non-blocking I/O (Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7).

My goal is to create a stock ticker-like API to allow a client to request all the resources from an endpoint based on some criteria, and also receive new resources that are created after the initial request. Reactive MongoDB is the backing store. The basic `HandlerFunction` implementation looks like the below.

```
Mono<ServerResponse> getFoos(ServerRequest request) {
    ok().contentType(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
            .body(fooRepository.findAll(), Foo)
}
```

Obviously, this just returns all the `Foos` that are currently available, then the `Publisher` closes the connection and no new `Foos` are sent to the client. My question is about what pattern to use to add an infinite stream to this which can accept new entries?

1. Concat with some global `Publisher Bean` which I write new `Foos` to as they are created
2. Add an `onComplete` which resubscribes to the `Repository` (with some criteria to filter duplicate entries)
3. Use `repeat` and let the client filter the duplicates
4. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure your MongoDB collection accordingly (it has to be capped), you can use tailable cursors to achieve what you want, just add a `@Tailable` annotation on your repository. See the [Spring Data MongoDB reference documentation about infinite streams](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.reactive.repositories.infinite-streams).

Comment: Just a follow up question on this. Does that mean , we need to create a separate collection(Capped) for this to work?

Comment: The collection needs to be capped indeed. That’s the condition to have this feature with MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks. New to MongoDB as well, and I didn't read the Mongo-specific section of the docs.